# emacs: how do I use edebug on code that is defined in a macro?

Tags: emacs, lisp

I don't even know the proper terminology for this lisp syntax, so I don't know if the words I'm using to ask the question, make sense.  But the question makes sense, I'm sure.

So let me just show you.  cc-mode (cc-fonts.el) has things called "matchers" which are bits of code that run to decide how to fontify a region of code. That sounds simple enough, but the matcher code is in a form I don't completely understand, with backticks and comma-atsign and just comma and so on, and furthermore it is embedded in a c-lang-defcost, which itself is a macro. I don't know what to call all that, but I want to run edebug on that code.

Look:

```
 (c-lang-defconst c-basic-matchers-after
   "Font lock matchers for various things that should be fontified after
 generic casts and declarations are fontified.  Used on level 2 and
 higher."

   t `(;; Fontify the identifiers inside enum lists.  (The enum type
       ;; name is handled by `c-simple-decl-matchers' or
       ;; `c-complex-decl-matchers' below.
       ,@(when (c-lang-const c-brace-id-list-kwds)
           `((,(c-make-font-lock-search-function
                (concat
                 "\\<\\("
                 (c-make-keywords-re nil (c-lang-const c-brace-id-list-kwds))
                 "\\)\\>"
                 ;; Disallow various common punctuation chars that can't come
                 ;; before the '{' of the enum list, to avoid searching too far.
                 "[^\]\[{}();,/#=]*"
                 "{")
                '((c-font-lock-declarators limit t nil)
                  (save-match-data
                    (goto-char (match-end 0))
                    (c-put-char-property (1- (point)) 'c-type
                                         'c-decl-id-start)
                    (c-forward-syntactic-ws))
                  (goto-char (match-end 0)))))))
```

I am reading up on lisp syntax to figure out what those things are and what to call them, but aside from that,  how can I run edebug on the code that follows the comment that reads `;; Fontify the identifiers inside enum lists.`  ?

I know how to run edebug on a defun - just invoke `edebug-defun` within the function's definition, and off I go.  Is there a corresponding thing I need to do to edebug the cc-mode matcher code forms?

What does `def-edebug-spec` do, and would I use it here?  If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `(elisp)Top > Debugging > Edebug > Edebug and Macros` you have to tell Edebug how to debug a macro by defining it with `debug` statements or by using `def-edebug-spec`.  This tells it what parameters should be evaluated and which shouldn't.  So it can be done.  In fact it looks as if `c-lang-defconst` already been fitted for `edebug`.  Here is the definition in case you were interested:

```
(def-edebug-spec c-lang-defconst
  (&define name [&optional stringp] [&rest sexp def-form]))
```

However, if you just want to see what the body evaluates to, then the way to do that is to use something like `macro-expand-last-sexp` below to see the result. Position your cursor after the sexp you want expanded (as you would for `C-x C-e`) and run `M-x macro-expand-last-sexp RET`.  This will show you what it gets expanded to.  You may run into troubles if you try to expand something like `,(....)` so you may have to copy that sexp somewhere else and delete the `,` or `,@`.

```
(defun macro-expand-last-sexp (p)
  "Macro expand the previous sexp.  With a prefix argument
insert the result into the current buffer and pretty print it."
  (interactive "P")
  (let*
      ((sexp (preceding-sexp))
       (expanded (macroexpand sexp)))
    (cond ((eq sexp expanded)
           (message "No changes were found when macro expanding"))
          (p
           (insert (format "%S" expanded))
           (save-excursion
             (backward-sexp)
             (indent-pp-sexp 1)
             (indent-pp-sexp)))
          (t
           (message "%S" expanded)))))
```

I guess it depends on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe edebug handles the backtick macro (`), and its special constructs for inlining ( , and ,@ ) properly.  There is not a way to use edebug on just a subexpression within a definition.  Instead, you have to instrument the whole defun or top-level expression.

Answer (score 5):

Use `macroexpand` or `macroexpand-all` to turn it into macro-free code and debug as usual?

Backticks &co may be best illustrated by an example:

```
(let ((a 1)
      (b (list 2 3)))
  `(a ,a ,b   ,@b))
-> (a  1 (2 3) 2 3)
```

A backtick (or backquote`` ` ``) is similar to a quote(`'`) in that it prevents evaluation, except its effect can be selectively undone with a comma(`,`); and `,@` is like `,`, except that its argument, which must be a list, is spliced into the resulting list.